# ¿Cuál sería la versión femenina de "caballero" como sustantivo?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sustantivos, género

En el diccionario se define *caballero* como sustantivo de la siguiente forma:

> **[caballero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6OGpVP7)**
>
> Del lat. *caballarius* 'caballerizo'.
>
> 3. m. Hombre que se comporta con distinción, nobleza y generosidad. *Se portó como un caballero.*

Esta definición se refiere exclusivamente a los hombres. El caso es que ayer, tras una serie de reflexiones de carácter filosófico acabé preguntándome cuál sería la palabra adecuada para referirse a una mujer que exhibe un comportamiento como el descrito por esta acepción.

En un principio se me ocurren:

> **[dama](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BqCXb3I)**
>
> Del fr. *dame*, y este del lat. *domĭna*.
>
> 1. f. Mujer noble o distinguida.

Y:

> **[señora](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XcBNzxH)**
>
> Del lat. *senior, -ōris* 'más viejo'.
>
> 4. m. y f. Persona que muestra dignidad en su comportamiento o aspecto.

Sin embargo, ninguna de las dos me termina de convencer. *Señora* es la versión femenina de *señor*, no de *caballero*. Y de *dama* no estoy seguro. Si la uso en la frase que aparece como ejemplo en la acepción de caballero:

> Se portó como una dama.

¿Se entiende lo mismo que con *caballero* pero en versión femenina? ¿O es el significado diferente? Nótese que en la acepción de *caballero* dice "que se comporta con", mientras que en la de *dama* no habla del comportamiento, sino que *es* noble y dintinguida, lo que puede hacer que el significado varíe. Si no, pongamos estos otros ejemplos:

> Juan es un auténtico caballero.
>   María es una auténtica dama.

¿Se puede entender por las definiciones que Juan tiene el comportamiento de un caballero (nobleza y distinción), pero que María es una persona noble y distinguida de verdad? ¿O son ambas cosas lo mismo?

¿Se os ocurre alguna otra alternativa?

> <sub>NOTA: El debate filosófico que generó esta duda fue: En un mundo en el que hay plena y absoluta igualdad entre el hombre y la mujer, ¿seguiría existiendo la [caballerosidad](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6OHw5OP)? (Entendida la "distinción, nobleza y generosidad" del *caballero* como del hombre hacia la mujer.)</sub>

Comment: Muchos discursos empiezan con "Damas y caballeros". Creo que eso confirma la relación entre los dos términos.

Comment: Con respecto al debate filosófico: la caballerosidad bien entendida no es sólo hacia las mujeres. El deportista que no hace trampa y admite la derrota gallardamente, o el hombre que cumple su palabra, o se asegura de que el comprador no esté cometiendo un error al comprarle... se están comportando como verdaderos caballeros, aunque no haya damas presentes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es correcto, la versión femenina de caballero es

> **dama**

Cuando hablamos de un caballero y/o dama hacemos referencia a una persona que tiene **conducta**.

Aunque la definición de señora este bien, no voy muy de acuerdo a su definición, al menos no en el uso de la vida real.

Todas las señoras pueden ser señoras por ser mujeres y por sus distinciones de género, de carácter cultural y social que se le atribuyen, así como a las diferencias sexuales y biológicas frente al hombre. Sin embargo, **pocas** pueden tener dignidad en su comportamiento o aspecto, lo que hace la diferencia entre ser una señora y una dama.

Otro uso, al menos en México, es que nos referimos a señora a cualquier mujer que ya tuvo un bebe o que ya se ha casado sin importar su edad, comportamiento, aspecto, raza, etcétera.

En resumen:

- Dama: Es aquella mujer que tiene valores, que respeta, se da a respetar, es amable, que aplica los buenos modales en todos los momentos y circunstancias de la vida, se sabe comportar en todos los ambientes, con cualquier persona, y nunca hace sentir menos a los que la rodean. Una dama es un **conjunto de virtudes y valores**.
- Señora: Una señora es cualquier femenina por derecho de nacimiento.

Answer (score 2):

No son exactamente sinónimos, soy hispanohablante, mi lengua nativa es el español.

Explicación de lo que yo entiendo: un caballero no es lo mismo que una dama cambiando el género. Caballero suena más a edad media, como dama. Si nos ponemos en el contexto, en esa época había mucho machismo por lo tanto los comportamientos no pueden ser los mismos, pero sí equivalentes.

Ejemplo: si un hombre deja pasar a una señora por delante, al pasar una puerta diríamos que es un caballero, pero sin embargo si la mujer deja pasar por delante al hombre al atravesar una puerta, no diríamos que por ello es una dama.

Comment: Sexismos aparte, puedes ver la situación que planteas como si alguien joven le cede su puesto en el bus a una persona mayor. Si es hombre, se diría que chico es caballero, si es mujer, la chica sería una dama...

Comment: Dama suele referirse a otro tipo de comportamientos, una dama no es alguien que crece su asiento en el bus, pero caballero si

Comment: Yo creo que lo que tienen en común la _dama_ y el _caballero_ es que se comportan según un catálogo de valores que la generación viva más antigua del momento considera que representan mejor lo que se espera de hombres y mujeres. Por supuesto que estos comportamientos esperables son distintos para cada sexo, y que cambian según la época. Y me imagino que, aunque ambas palabras se desprestigien y se pierdan como antigüedades, el concepto de "dama" y "caballero" seguirá existiendo, pero asociado a comportamientos muy distintos.

Answer (score 1):

¿Y cuando se habla de un miembro de la caballería?

La palabra “caballero” tiene varias connotaciones:

Damas y Caballeros, resulta apropiado cuando se hace referencia al sexo de un grupo de personas de las cuales se espera un comportamiento asociado a su sexo.

Por otra parte, “caballero” como miembro de la caballería (grupo de militares que desempeñan actividades especificas que se distinguen de la infantería, la artillería, etc) no tiene como femenino “dama”. En este caso, “caballera” o “una caballero” resultan más apropiados.

De acuerdo con la RAE, “una caballera” resulta apropiado. Sin embargo, como hispano hablante, no me suena natural. Yo agregaría “miembro, oficial, soldado, mujer, etc. De caballería”.

Un caballero ‘ Una caballera / una oficial de caballería.

Agregando la palabra extra se elimina cualquier controversia o duda, que a la larga debería ser el objetivo del escrito.

Answer (score 1):

En principio diría que el término "dama" es a una mujer lo que "caballero" es a un hombre. Sin embargo, cuando empiezo a pensar en situaciones donde utilizarla hay pocas en las que no me suene raro. De hecho, solo su uso en plural me suena bien. El "Damas y caballeros" para empezar un discurso, las rotulaciones en los baños de las mujeres, etc. Pero como saludo cuando se trata de una sola persona me suena raro: "Buenos días, dama". En cambio, el equivalente para caballero "Buenos días, caballero" es bastante común y por eso me suena familiar.

Answer (score 0):

Caballero, para Gen. Masculino.
Gentileza para Gen. Femenino.

Ambos por definición, es el acto de seducción, respeto, atención y cortesía hacia una persona o grupo de personas específicas. Ejemplo:

- Él hacia Ella.
- Ella hacia Él.
- Él y/o Ella hacia Ellos (amigos, familia, etc).

Si el acto por definición se hace hacia un público en general se le llama.
Atento(a) ó Servicial.

Cabe mencionar que a este último concepto no tiene nada que ver con el sentido de sirviente.

Servir es un acto de función,
Sirviente un acto por contrato u obligación hacía una(s) persona específica.

Un ejemplo de ello.
Jesus sirvió al mundo, mas no fue sirviente de nadie.

Saludos desde México.

Comment: No veo en la definición de [_gentileza_](https://dle.rae.es/gentileza) nada que haga pensar que es el femenino de _caballero_, sino que es más bien un sinónimo de _cortesía_. ¿Tal vez podrías poner una frase de ejemplo donde se pueda sustituir "caballero" por "gentileza" sin variar su significado?

Comment: Estos son ajetivos, no sustantivos.

Answer (score 0):

El equivalente de caballero es dama, incluso referido a mujer de una orden de caballería.

Caballero significa hoy hombre distinguido y noble, porque los soldados   a caballo (casi siempre hombres, pese a lo que se ve ahora en las series de supuesta recreación -- reinvención -- histórica) han constituido siempre una  élite, distinguidos (bien vestidos) y si no eran ya directamente nobles se convertían en una especie de baja nobleza de hecho o de derecho (lo armaban  caballero) y por eso surgen las órdenes de caballeria, que como cualquier órden militar, era una forma de afianzar el estatus de una élite militar.

Y caballera no suena natural porque las mujeres, entraban en esas órdenes, no por montar a caballo  (aunque a veces lo hicieran) o por ser guerreras (aunque alguna hubo) sino por ser esposas de caballero, con el título de «dame» (de origen  francés: madame = mi esposo) o como reconocimiento de su alta posición social («dame» viene del latín  «domĭna», dueña), que supongo entonces era más apropiado que «señora» (que viene del latín «senior», que entonces no era lengua muerta, así que significaba literalmente «vieja»).